# Has any etymologist entertained the possibility that "carpa" (carp) and "carassius" (crucian carp) are related?

Tags: etymology, animals, biology

As far as I can see, "*carpa*" (carp) appeared in Late Latin and it is usually considered to be a borrowing from an unattested Gothic word for that fish. "*Carassius*" also appeared in Late Latin and is of unclear etymology, the most commonly cited etymologies being that it is somehow related to Ancient Greek fish name *korakinos* or that it is of Slavic origin.

I consider it at least probable that the Illyrian language had a word *karr~kurr which meant "*to flow*". Namely, as I argue in [a paper I published in Valpovački Godišnjak and Regionalne Studije in 2022](https://flatassembler.github.io/Karasica.doc), a disproportionate number of river names in Croatia start with k-r, and the p-value of that pattern (as can be calculated using birthday calculations adjusted for the collision entropy of the Croatian language) is somewhere between 1/300 and 1/17. So, I am wondering, how plausible it is that the fish names "*carpa*" and "*carassius*" are related and both come from the Illyrian word for "to flow"?

Has any etymologist suggested a connection between "*carpa*" and "*carassius*"?

Comment: *Carassius* is Linnaeus' latinisation of German *Karausche* and was never real Latin. *Karausche* might be a borrowing from Latin *coracinus*, itself certainly from Greek κορακῖνος 'young raven; some Nile fish'. The PIE root *\*(s)ker-* 'to cut' underlying that, or the homonymous one 'to bend', could conceivably have yielded lexical items related to rivers flowing, maybe, but none seem to survive in Albanian. Either way, you'd still have to explain the *p* in *carpa*.